# Headset bluetooth scanned as unknown on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, headset

I got bluetooth headset some days ago and since then I've tried to pair it with my notebook that contains Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it, but it hasn't worked so far. In order to pair it I tried blueman and other tools, but none of them solved the problem. It turned out the headset wasn't identified correctly by the tools, the headset was scanned as a unknown device. However, the same headset works like magic with my Android phone. What am I really missing to make it work on my Ubuntu? I've tried a different bluetooth headset and it worked without any problem on Ubuntu, but that specific one aforementioned seems not to be recognized properly by my Ubuntu.